# Attach template to a word document through JAVA

Tags: java, ms-word

Can anyone help me to attach a template to a word document through Java coding.

Answer (score 0):

If you know how to do this in VBA, you can use Com4J, generate the JavaProxies for Word, and then call the same functions from Java.

Comment: I have VBA coding for attaching tenplates as below:

Comment: As below what? I assume you mistook the answer field for a continuation of the comment field.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) that provides cross platform pure Java solution for manipulating MS Office documents.

Answer (score 0):

with docx4j:

```
    // Create settings part, and init content
    DocumentSettingsPart dsp = new DocumentSettingsPart();
    CTSettings settings = Context.getWmlObjectFactory().createCTSettings();
    dsp.setJaxbElement(settings);
    wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().addTargetPart(dsp);

    // Create external rel
    RelationshipsPart rp = RelationshipsPart.createRelationshipsPartForPart(dsp);       
    org.docx4j.relationships.Relationship rel = new org.docx4j.relationships.ObjectFactory().createRelationship();
    rel.setType( "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/attachedTemplate"  );
    rel.setTarget("file:///C:\\Users\\jsmith\\AppData\\Roaming\\Microsoft\\Templates\\yours.dotm");
    rel.setTargetMode("External");          
    rp.addRelationship(rel); // addRelationship sets the rel's @Id

    settings.setAttachedTemplate(
            (CTRel)XmlUtils.unmarshalString("<w:attachedTemplate xmlns:w=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main\" xmlns:r=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships\" r:id=\"" + rel.getId() + "\"/>", Context.jc, CTRel.class)
            );
```

See org.docx4j.samples.TemplateAttach in docx4j svn for the complete example.